# Audio playback from two bluetooth devices stopped working

Tags: audio, bluetooth-audio

I have a Galaxy S10e running Android 12, and two bluetooth speakers. I connected to both of them and enabled "audio" playback in the settings. A notification popped up stating that my device is able to stream music to the two speakers at once and if I want to enable this. I did, and it worked fine: I was able to control the volume of both of the speakers separately. Note that I do not see this setting directly in the Advanced tab of the Bluetooth Settings.

That happened the first time I tried connecting the two speakers. Ever since then, when I connect the speakers, the notification does not pop up and only one of them is playing music. Switching the "audio" playback on and off in the bluetooth setting simply switches which one actually plays music.

Does anyone know how I can access the settings for dual playback again? I tried unpairing the devices to maybe trigger whatever happened the first time to no avail, and don't really have any ideas why the dual playback feature stopped being an option.

Thanks for any help!
-Tusike

Answer (score 1):

After searching all around the phone I found that the settings menu you get to by pulling down the touchscreen from the top actually has a "Media output" panel that can be immediately seen, and the dual audio controls can be found there.

Comment: You need to tell readers how to get to it or post a screendhot or both.